# WPF binding List<KeyValuePair<,>> to DataGrid using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I want to display all the NetworkInterfaces of my computer via DataGrid and i have the following class for (that is the .xaml.cs Controller):

```
public partial class Network : Window
{
    public Network()
    {
        PrintStatus();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void PrintStatus()
    {
        var bindingList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

        foreach (NetworkInterface card in networkCards)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(NetworkInterface).GetProperties())
                bindingList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(card, null)));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried like following, but that doesn't work:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NetInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=bindingList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>    
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In VisualStudio when i move my mouse over Key or Value in the `Binding` tag i get the message that ***it cannot be resolved due to unknow DataContext***.

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong so, as you can see i don't really understand how Databindings work ^^.

Comment: use the property  public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> bindingList { get; set; }  and add values to this property inside PrintStatus() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `bindingList` is a local variable in `PrintStatus()`. It's invisible outside that method. You need to put the items someplace where the view can get to them.

```
public Network()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    PrintStatus();
}


public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> BindingList { get; private set; }

public void PrintStatus()
{
    BindingList.Clear();

    foreach (NetworkInterface card in networkCards)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(NetworkInterface).GetProperties()) 
        {
            BindingList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(card, null)));
        }
    }
}
```

In the XAML, you need to bind to `BindingList` (I've changed your capitalization to match standard .NET practice) as a property of the window. It should be a member of your viewmodel. In that case you'd bind to `{Binding BindingList}`. But you don't have one, so that won't work.

By default, `DataGrid` automatically generates a column for each property in the items in the collection that you give it. Since you defined your own columns, by default it'll add yours to those. You can turn that off by setting `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, as below.

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="NetInfo" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BindingList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>    
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You could also let it go ahead and auto-generate the columns, and just refrain from defining your own. If you want to define your own headers, or change formatting, or even omit one or two columns that you don't care about, your original approach allows a lot more flexibility. Just covering all the bases.

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="NetInfo" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding BindingList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    />
```

`DataContext = this;` is bad practice. In a window it's relatively harmless, but as you can see above, it's never necessary. `RelativeSource` bindings are very easy to use. If you start making a habit of it, you'll break binding on properties of your user controls. And it always creates confusion.

Comment: Thank you it nearly works now, but a strange thing happened after changing the code to what you provided: the key and value columns and their contents are double like `Key | Value | Key | Value`

Comment: @MartinNiederl Whoops, see update: I added `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to `DataGrid`. You could get the same effect by leaving that out (the default for that property is True), and omitting `DataGrid.Columns` -- I'll add that update in a moment.

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. I chose the one liner for my example but i won't forget how to use the other one if you have to format the cols or rename them e.g